# Get value from an odata property in a JSON response using ajax

Tags: json, ajax, razor, onedrive

I need to get the value for @odata.context property from the following Json response in ajax:

```
 {
  "@odata.context":"https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/",
  "@odata.type":"#oneDrive.permission",
  "@odata.id":"https",
  "link":{"scope":"anonymous"}
 }
```

I  would like to do something like that in code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + bearerToken);
        },
        url: serverUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: " application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            var myvalue= data.@odata.context;  // ****???
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);  //this line throws an error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get data by this:

```
data["@odata.context"]
```

And about the JSON.parse throw exception, it caused by the data is not a JSON string.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7RqX.png)

Comment: I have tried this at chrome console, it works. Please check it with my screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just don't know why u say it is not a Json string?

Comment: Because the data you accepted at success function is a javascript object not a JSON string.

Comment: Alright. I guess that it is because of the dataType set to 'json' , which converts it into a java script object automatically. Anyway, thanks for your solution.